Can I create a Foreign Key from an entity using a field that belongs to a different entity?
I have a Receipt entity, that can link to a MatchedMerchantReturnLine entity. This MatchedMerchantReturnLine entity has a OurOrderNumber property.
I'd like to link the Receipt entity to a OrderLineContractNumbers entity via this property (and another on the Receipt entity, but that's not the issue).
e.g:
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLineContractNumbers>().HasMany(r => r.Receipts)
    .WithOne(r => r.OrderNumberDetails)
    .HasForeignKey(r => new { r.MatchedMerchantReturnLine.OurOrderNumber, r.Item })

This doesn't work however, with the error:
The expression 'r => new <>f__AnonymousType3`2(OurOrderNumber = r.MatchedMerchantReturnLine.OurOrderNumber, Item = r.Item)' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties or fields, use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty, t.MyField }'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')

I've also tried creating a property on the Receipt object:
public string OurOrderNumber => MatchedMerchantReturnLine?.OurOrderNumber;

and referring to that:
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLineContractNumbers>().HasMany(r => r.Receipts)
    .WithOne(r => r.OrderNumberDetails)
    .HasForeignKey(r => new { r.OurOrderNumber, r.Item })

however then I get the error message as below:
No backing field could be found for property 'MerchantReturnReceipt.OurOrderNumber' and the property does not have a setter.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm after here?

No, AFAIK you cannot do anything like that. Think of it from the database point of view. Columns on the particular tables in question need to exist on both sides, typically a PK on one side and a single FK on the other (though you can use FKs on both sides) You cannot have a PK/FK on one side, and then the other side somehow matches up using a FK on a third table.  Start with how you think the tables will actually wire up.

@Steve It could make sense from a JOIN perspective fine. I'd link the Receipt table and MatchedMerchantReturnLine table together, then use those to link to the 3rd table using a field from Receipt and a field from MatchedMerchantReturnLine. I guess I'll probably have to just do it without using navigation properties if they can't (or aren't designed to) handle that scenario.
